# probability of $4$ players scoring more then $50$ runs

Tags: probability

> The probability of $4$ crickters $A,B,C,D$ scoring more then $50$ runs in a match are $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{10}.$ It is known that exactly two players scored more then $50$ runs in a perticular match. Then the probability that these players where $A$ and $B$ is

Try: From definition of question, it is based

on Bayes Theorem

So probability of a players scoring more then

$50$ runs in a match is

$\displaystyle P(A) = \frac{1}{2}\;\;,P(B) = \frac{1}{3}\;\;,P(C) = \frac{1}{4}\;\;, P(D) = \frac{1}{10}$

Now probability of selecting two players (i.e $AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$) scoring more then $50$ runs is

$\displaystyle P(\text{selecting 2 players } ) = \frac{1}{6}$

Now i did not understand how to solve it

could some help me , Thanks

Comment: Sketch:  for each pair, compute the probability that those two (and no others) scored over $50$ and add. Then the answer is the portion of the sum which is explained by the pair $AB$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the probability that exactly the players $A$ and $B$ score more than $50$ runs in a match is
$$P(AB\bar{C}\bar{D})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{9}{10}.$$
where $\bar{C}$ and $\bar{D}$ are the complements of $C$ and of $D$ respectively.

Now we know that one of the following $\binom{4}{2}=6$ events happened $AB\bar{C}\bar{D},A\bar{B}C\bar{D}, \dots,\bar{A}\bar{B} CD$.

Can you take it from here?